# is there a way to get the thumb for any file type?

Tags: javascript, php, file, thumbnails, preview

I would like to provide a thumb to most common file types:

- images (i can already do that, haha)
- documents: .zip, .doc, .xls, ...
- videos: .avi, .mpg, .flv, ..

and maybe others,

is there a nice plugin to do so? (if needed)

my website its built with PHP/JS

Comment: You can only do this on the server. The JavaScript tag doesn't really apply here.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with JS as well. Just parse the href parameter and check the extension and add some HTML code to load the thumbnail.

Comment: ffmpeg will handle the video types, imagemagick 'convert' can handle pdf, but I can't think of anything that'll render a doc/xls/ppt/etc.. on the server without having OpenOffice or MS Office installed. Most libraries for those file types are concerned about reading/writing them, *not* rendering them.

Comment: @Rasika: and how will that thumbnail be generated? OP isn't talking about just displaying the thumbnail, he needs to render/generate them to begin with.

Comment: Opps, just thought of the icons not thumbnails.

Comment: @Raiska, now i do. Is there nice plugin with icons that you might know? :$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and no, there is no nice plugin for it AFAIK.

Every file has its own "encoding", so you basically need to "decode" every file, which is a nontrivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Give it a chance. I'm using it in my own apps. Of course, it's just for images (as well as i know). But, works really good. If you find something to make a thumb for PDF files share it!